# Any progress with programming Java for iOS?

Tags: java, ios, code-translation

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050943/how-can-one-develop-iphone-apps-in-java#) I realized that now it's around 5 years later, and I kept hearing that translators are getting better and better.

Is there CURRENTLY really any professional way of developing in java for iOS mobile systems?

Thanks

Comment: Odd that the original 5 year old question gets 31 up votes, but someone asking for an updated answer gets several down votes.

Comment: Not really an appropriate question for SO as this could easily be researched. If you Googled first you probably would have found answers

Comment: People get overexcited by yet another translator, that is why I asked SO, I don't think that sifting through their efficiency is something that a simple Googling would expose :-(

Comment: @ThomasN. I think you misunderstand the mission of StackOverflow. **Easily googled Questions are perfectly acceptable** here. Indeed, having StackOverflow appear as a top Google search hit was a primary goal when inventing StackOverflow. See blog posts by Spolsky announcing its invention, [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html) and [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). The main requirement for a Question is that it be narrow and specific. Complicated and difficult are *not* requirements.

Comment: Okay fair enough... but a question should be somewhat researched and show effort, i guess that part is a bit of a grey area to me then. But to the OP, you might want to take a look at Gluon http://gluonhq.com/

Comment: @ThomasN. Nope, being “somewhat researched and showing effort” is *not* required for StackOverflow.com Questions, contrary to occasional posted comments. Only questions of the type “why isn't this code working?” need [A] show some coherent thought in terms of a “clear problem statement”, and [B] include the “shortest code necessary”… both of which usually means some research and some effort. [See the description when you click the "Close" link > "Off topic because" > "Questions seeking debugging help…"]

Answer (score 1):

Using Robovm and libgdx are the best way I've found to compile to iOS.

RoboVM: robovm.com
libgdx: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com

RoboVM uses a AOT (Ahead-of-time) compiler to convert the Java code before it's packaged to iOS

libgdx provides a library that is  compatible with Android, Desktop, iOS, and HTML

Answer (score 1):

I heard of the Gluon project which is bridging JavaFX and Java to iOS and Android. I think it looks pretty promising, and I worked on Github with one of its founders. I think they'll pull together something pretty neat http://gluonhq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Intel has recently introduced INDE Multi-OS Engine early access programm: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde-multi-os-early-access

Good technical overview is here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/07/30/multi-os-engine-of-intel-inde-technical-overview

[image]

It let's to create Java applications in Android Studio for both iOS and Android platforms with a possibility to share logic between them.

Also there is a way to develop an app on Windows-host with Mac build server in LAN.

[image]