# how can make an application for IOS in java?

Tags: java, ios

I know that you can create an iOS application on Xcode if you own a mac either using swift or objective-c code. How can I go about creating an IOS app with java or on a regular windows computer in a different programming language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050943/how-can-one-develop-iphone-apps-in-java

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can't distribute iOS apps from non-mac OS.

Nevertheless, you have such options as [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com) for creating iOS apps using C#, or [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) - using JS, but, again, you won't be able to distribute, or even compile it for try, without Mac

UPDATE

Have just tried React Native and it's possible to view how your app will look like without mac

Answer (score 2):

You can create **hybrid** mobile apps using
**Ionic**.
Ionic is an open-source front-end framework for creating mobile apps with HTML5 and JavaScript. Since the apps are loaded in user's browser you won't need of a mac for developing mobile apps and will be compatible for iOS, android, etc.

Find out more here http://ionicframework.com/

Additional technologies:
You may also like to try NativeScript https://www.nativescript.org/, it's cross-platform for developing **native** iOS and Android, using angular with TypeScript or pure Javascript, unfortunately you will need a mac to compile, test and distribute iOS apps.