# can we make iOS and MacOs apps using java?

Tags: java, ios, macos

I was wondering whether or not we can make iOS and MacOS apps using java 
If we can which software is advisable ?

Comment: If you use C# instead of Java, you can use Xamarin.

Comment: Also, this may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050943/how-can-one-develop-iphone-apps-in-java).

Comment: This post shows an astonishing lack of effort. Surely some time in Google would answer the first half, and the second half (asking for a software recommendation) is clearly mentioned as being off-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X / Can I do X? / Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for the Stack Overflow format.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can just install java in mac and netbeans IDE, the procedure is below:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/learn-set-up-java-programming-environment-in-os-x-3636924/

1: Java Install Procedure:
https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml

2: Netbeans Download Link:
https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

--Have Fun and happy coding!-- :)

Comment: Please don't encourage bad questions by answering them.

Comment: @KubaOber I agree I will take care of this from now :)